# Reddit Bot Stops commenting after certain time

Tags: python, bots, reddit, jreddit, redditkit

I have been trying to make a bot that searches for a specific keyword in the reddit title, if that keyword is true it would then comment something in that thread. Everything works find, just I have one problem, after around 4 hours of it running it keeps searching but it stops commenting for some reason, no idea why. Then I restart it and it works ok.

It seems to happen around 3pm PST everyday, it keeps on printing that it is searching but it just wont comment even if there are posts that contain the keywords. Is this somehting that reddit does to stop bots or is something wrong with my code.

Before I had the reddit praw statement ouside of my 3 subreddit functions, but I wanted to test if i kept on reconnecting to the prawl after every seach would it stop the issue.

In sort my reddit bot stops commenting after a certain point and is there any way I could fix this or is it permanent.

```html
    #!/usr/bin/python
import praw
import pdb
import re
import os
import threading
import time

sub1_array = ['Title']
sub1_array = ['Comment']   

def sub1():

    reddit = praw.Reddit('bot1')

    if not os.path.isfile("posts_replied_to.txt"):
        posts_replied_to = []
        
    else:
        with open("posts_replied_to.txt", "r") as f:
            posts_replied_to = f.read()
            posts_replied_to = posts_replied_to.split("\n")
            posts_replied_to = list(filter(None, posts_replied_to))

    subreddit = reddit.subreddit('sub1')
    print("Checking sub1")
    for submission in subreddit.new(limit=20):
        i = 0

        while i <= (len(sub1_array) - 1):

        # If we haven't replied to this post before
            if submission.id not in posts_replied_to:
        
            # Do a case insensitive search
                if re.search(sub1_array[i], submission.title, re.IGNORECASE):
                    # Reply to the post
                    submission.reply(link_array[i])
                    print("Bot replying to match: ", submission.title)
                    del sub1_array[i]
                    del sub1_array[i]
                    posts_replied_to.append(submission.id)
                    time.sleep(100)

                else:
                    i += 1
            else:
                i += 1
    with open("posts_replied_to.txt", "w") as f:
        for post_id in posts_replied_to:
            f.write(post_id + "\n")
sub2_array = ['Title']
sub2_link = ['Comment]

                
def sub2():
    reddit = praw.Reddit('bot1')


    if not os.path.isfile("posts_replied_to.txt"):
        posts_replied_to = []
        
    else:
        with open("posts_replied_to.txt", "r") as f:
            posts_replied_to = f.read()
            posts_replied_to = posts_replied_to.split("\n")
            posts_replied_to = list(filter(None, posts_replied_to))
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit('sub2')
    print("Checking Streams NBA")
    for submission in subreddit.new(limit=20):
        #print(submission.title)
        i = 0

    
        while i <= (len(sub2_array) - 1):

        # If we haven't replied to this post before
            if submission.id not in posts_replied_to:
        
            # Do a case insensitive search
                if re.search(sub2_array[i], submission.title, re.IGNORECASE):
                    # Reply to the post
                    submission.reply(sub2_link[i])
                    print("Bot replying to match: ", submission.title)
                    del sub2_array[i]
                    del sub2_array[i]
                    posts_replied_to.append(submission.id)
                    time.sleep(100)

                else:
                    i += 1
            else:
                i += 1
    with open("posts_replied_to.txt", "w") as f:
        for post_id in posts_replied_to:
            f.write(post_id + "\n")

sub3_array = ['Title']
sub3_link = ['Comment]
def ncaa():
    reddit = praw.Reddit('bot1')

    if not os.path.isfile("posts_replied_to.txt"):
        posts_replied_to = []
        
    else:
        with open("posts_replied_to.txt", "r") as f:
            posts_replied_to = f.read()
            posts_replied_to = posts_replied_to.split("\n")
            posts_replied_to = list(filter(None, posts_replied_to))
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit('sub3')
    print("Checking sub3")
    for submission in subreddit.new(limit=20):
        #print(submission.title)
        i = 0

    
        while i <= (len(sub3_array) - 1):

        # If we haven't replied to this post before
            if submission.id not in posts_replied_to:
        
            # Do a case insensitive search
                if re.search(sub3_array[i], submission.title, re.IGNORECASE):
                    # Reply to the post
                    submission.reply(sub3_link[i])
                    print("Bot replying to match: ", submission.title)
                    del sub3_array[i]
                    del sub3_array[i]
                    posts_replied_to.append(submission.id)
                    time.sleep(100)

                else:
                    i += 1
            else:
                i += 1
    with open("posts_replied_to.txt", "w") as f:
        for post_id in posts_replied_to:
            f.write(post_id + "\n")
                
                
def should_reset_timer():
  pass    

                
def main():
  sub1()
  sub2()
  sub3()
  timer = 0
  while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    timer+=1
    if should_reset_timer():
      timer = 0
    if timer == 1*30:
      sub1()
      sub2()
      sub3()
      timer = 0
  # Store the current id into our list

# Write our updated list back to the file


main()
```

Comment: Some websites restart their servers to fix the code and to let the server cool down.

Comment: The subreddit is still up when it happens and I can comment myself, just the bot can't

Comment: Why do you want to spam yourself?